# Заголовок у DataTables не правильного размера

Tags: javascript, ajax, table, datatable, таблицы

Вот так все выглядит, я в js не силен, но работу выполнить нужно.

[image: Вот так все выглядит, я в js не силен, но работу выполнить нужно.]

```
var table = $('table.long_bot_table').dataTable({
    // "scrollY": 200,
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    "info": false,
});
```

Данные заносятся через Ajax. Как я понимаю. Сначала генерируется DataTable, а потом только заносятся данные, из-за этого это происходит, как можно исправить, знатоки??

Comment: приведите код таблицы и ее стилей, думаю, проблема кроется в CSS стилях.

Comment: стили стандартные из datatable, код таблицы
<table>
<thead>
<tr>....</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>...</td>
</tbody>